# Graphics Flicker On Form Drag in c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, flicker

Graphics Flickering is a common question Here but my issue is different.
I have used this code to all child forms to avoid flickering in my MDI application.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

But after using this code graphics get weird when I drag the form. Check the screenshots.
Normal[image]

When I drag it.[image]

What's wrong?
**Edit:-** I am using all controls inside a panel in each form.

Comment: Needs a [mcve].

Comment: Are the forms all DoubleBuffered?

Comment: @TaW Yes all doublebuffered.

Comment: Try enabling double buffering on the MdiClient itself.  See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/99093134-b73a-47d9-8b59-f6d3bd4d2c45/flickerfree-for-mdiclient-vbnet?forum=winforms) for an example in C#.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I have done the same but still the same issue. :(